# Split the sentences by ',' and remove surrounding spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code:

```
var r = /(?:^\s*([^\s]*)\s*)(?:,\s*([^\s]*)\s*){0,}$/
var s = "   a   ,  b  , c "
var m = s.match(r)
m => ["   a   ,  b  , c ", "a", "c"]
```

Looks like the whole string has been matched, but where has `"b"` gone? I would rather expect to get:

```
["   a   ,  b  , c ", "a", "b", "c"]
```

so that I can do `m.shift()` with a result like `s.split(',')` but also with whitespaces removed.

Do I have a mistake in the regexp or do I misunderstand `String.prototype.match`?

Comment: As a side note, `{0,}` is the same as `*`.

Comment: well, `s` may also be `'  a, c'` or `'a,b,c     d e, f'`

Comment: i'll change spaces to \s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

so finally i went with `/(?=\S)[^,]+?(?=\s*(,|$))/g`, which provides exactly what i need: all sentences split by ',' without surrounding spaces.

```
'       a,    OMG     abc b a b, d o WTF        foo     '.
  match( /(?=\S)[^,]+?(?=\s*(,|$))/g )
=> ["a", "OMG     abc b a b", "d o WTF        foo"]
```

many thanks!

Comment: here is the meaning as i understand it. please correct me if i'm not right:
`(?=\S)` - start capturing only when there's no whitespace in front
`[^,]+` - capture as much 'not-commas' as possible
`?` - but don't capture what can be captured by the next group
`(?=\s*(,|$))` - capture all whitespaces before a comma or end of string
`/g` - repeat through all the string

Answer (score 283):

Here's a pretty simple & straightforward way to do this without needing a complex regular expression.

```
var str = "   a   ,  b  , c "
var arr = str.split(",").map(function(item) {
  return item.trim();
});
//arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

The native `.map` is supported on IE9 and up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

---

Or in ES6+ it gets even shorter:

```
let arr = str.split(",").map(item => item.trim());
```

And for completion, here it is in Typescript with typing information

```
let arr: string[] = str.split(",").map((item: string) => item.trim());
```

Comment: Just to be picky, you can do away with the braces around the map argument:  

`var arr = str.split(",").map(item=>item.trim());`

Comment: I am with @DavidJones on this one. If you modify your answer would be great. Helped me a lot for my case, thank you guys!

Comment: Yep good point - answer updated to reflect that!  I personally always add the parentheses though since I'm usually writing Typescript, and I like to provide the explicit type information so you can always know what something is at a glance.

Comment: To prevent an array with an empty string,  use:   str.split(",").map(e => e.trim()).filter((e) => e.length)

Comment: To break on spaces and commas, and avoid empty string elements, use:  str.split(/[, ]/).filter((e) => e.length)

Answer (score 49):

ES6 shorthand:

```
str.split(',').map(item=>item.trim())
```

Answer (score 38):

You can try this without complex regular expressions.

```js
var arr = "   a   ,  b  , c ".trim().split(/\s*,\s*/);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This is the one I would use.

Answer (score 17):

Short answer: Use `m = s.match(/[^ ,]/g);`

---

Your RE doesn't work as expected, because the last group matches the most recent match (=`c`). If you omit `{1,}$`, the returned match will be `"   a   , b ", "a", "b"`. In short, your RegExp does return as much matches as specified groups **unless** you use a `global` flag `/g`. In this case, the returned list hold references to all matched substrings.

To achieve your effect, use:

```
m = s.replace(/\s*(,|^|$)\s*/g, "$1");
```

This replace replaces every comma (`,`), beginning (`^`) and end (`$`), surrounded by whitespace, by the original character (`comma`, or nothing).

If you want to get an array, use:

```
m = s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").split(/\s*,\s*/);
```

This RE trims the string (removes all whitespace at the beginning and end, then splits the string by `<any whitespace>,<any whitespace>`. Note that white-space characters also include newlines and tabs. If you want to stick to spaces-only, use a space () instead of `\s`.

Comment: @Andrew I've expanded the explanation of your RE. See my second example for a `split` method.

Comment: i have already posted it as a comment to another answer. i wonder, can i do it with one regexp and one operation or js regexp is not smart enough?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, just use `s.match(/[^ ,]+/g)`. As mentioned at the top of my answer, the `/g` is the global flag, which returns all matching substrings.

Comment: @Andrew: One capturing group creates one match, no matter how many quantifiers you add. If you want to match `a`, `b` and `c`, you need three pairs of parentheses (not including `(?:...)`): `/(?:^\s*([^\s]*)\s*)(?:,\s*([^\s]*)\s*)(?:,\s*([^\s]*)\s*)$/`

Comment: @RobW, s.match(/[^ ,]+/g) works exactly as i need, please add it to your answer

Comment: Andrew, I don't think /[^ ,]+/g is what you want. It matches spaces in between words also. I thought you don't want to match spaces in between words. For ex. 'abc def'.match(/[^ ,]+/g) gives ['abc', 'def']. And 'abc def'.match(/[^ ,]/g) gives ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

Comment: @Narendra If that's really an issue, this RE will do (looks somewhat complex for a novice though, I don't want to scare him): `m=s.match(/(?!,\s*|^\s*)(?=[^,\s])[^,]+?(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g);`.

Comment: @Andrew: As I said, it's like you get what you ask for. Create n groups to get n matches. Guess it just doesn't work the you want it. BTW: I'm pretty sure that's the same in any RE engine, not just in JS.

Comment: @RobW, can i shorten your expression as /(?!^\s*|,\s*)\S+?(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g or do i miss something only a regexp ninja could sight? =)

Comment: At your RegExp, white-space characters aren't allowed any more. So at, `a, b c, d`, the match will be `a,c,d`, which is wrong. Use the following pattern (I have applied once change: `^\s*` is changed to `^\s+`, to prevent `^` from being rejected: `/(?!,\s*|^\s+)(?=[^,\s])[^,]+?(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g`.

Comment: looks like now i understand the purpose of `(?=[^,\s])`. you tell it: start matching only when there is something that is neither space nor comma in front of us. am i right?
i think then we can shorten the regexp to: `/(?=\S)[^,]+?(?=\s*(,|$))/g`

Comment: @meandre It's more efficient to write `/(?=\S)[^,]+?(?=\s*(?:,|$)/g`. It's *slightly* faster, because each group results in a new reference, unless it's a **non-captured group**, created using `(?:...)`. See this JSPerf: http://jsperf.com/regexp-group-test

Answer (score 12):

If you want to keep using regular expression, keep the code simple and without using ES6:

```
s.replace(/ /g, '').split(",")
```

1 - Replace all the spaces (/ /g) by empty strings ('')

2 - Then split it into an array

Et voila

Comment: This is the best, least-complicated answer.

Comment: `s.replace(/\s/g, '').split(",")` best now

Comment: This won't work for data such as `'       a,    OMG     abc b a b, d o WTF        foo     '` (see [OPs self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7873580/9473764))

Answer (score 9):

You can do this for your purpose 
**EDIT**: Removing second replace as suggested in the comments.
`s.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'').split(/\s*,\s*/)` 
First `replace` trims the string and then the `split` function splits around `'\s*,\s*'` . This gives output `["a", "b", "c"]` on input  `"   a   ,  b  , c "`

As for why your regex is not capturing 'b', you are repeating a captured group, so only the last occurrence gets captured. More on that here http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

Comment: i don't want to erase all whitespaces, only around commas or at the beginning/end of a string

Comment: @Andrew isnt’t that all whitespaces? or do you have sentences you wish to split?

Comment: s.replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '').split(/\s*,\s*/) can do this

Comment: @Andrew Changed the answer according to your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the below snippet if the comma separated list has large number of values:

`data.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/)`

Answer (score 0):

The pattern in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7873580/5424988) can be written without the leading lookahead `(?=\S)` by using a negated character class `[^\s,]` to match a single non whitespace character except a comma.

**Note** that the [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^,]` can also match a newline. If you don't want to match across lines, you can use `[^,\n]`

```
[^\s,][^,]*?(?=\s*(?:,|$))
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZUwVR/1).

---

This regex can be simplified without non greedy quantifiers to an optional part, ending on a non whitespace char which is not a comma.

```
[^\s,](?:[^,]*[^\s,])?
```

**Explanation**

- `[^\s,]` match a non whitespace character except a comma
- `(?:` Non capture group
- `[^,]*` Repeat 0+ times matching any character except a comma
- `[^\s,]` match a single whitespace character except a comma
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HoxB1E/1).

```js
const regex = /[^\s,](?:[^,\n]*[^\s,])?/g;
const s = "   a   ,  b  , c ";
const m = s.match(regex);
console.log(m);
```

---

You can also use split, but the difference is that if you have a string like this `,  ,a,` and your split on `\s*,\s*` you will still have empty entries which you don't have when using [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```js
console.log(`,  ,a,`.split(/\s*,\s*/));
```