# Convert large txt file to any structured format

Tags: javascript, node.js, text

I have a large txt file which has space separated 'columns', I want to be able to convert it to something like JSON,xlsx,csv etc so I can perform programmatic operations on the data.

The file is huge so I wont post the whole thing - here is a snippet to get an example though:

```
ID number Name                              TitlFed  Grade GamesBorn Flag
10207538  A E M, Doshtagir                      BAN  1864    0        i
10206612  A K M, Sourab                         BAN  1714    0        i
 5045886  A K, Kalshyan                         IND  1958    0  1964  
 8605360  A La, Teng Hua                        CHN  1915    0  1993  wi
 5031605  A, Akshaya                            IND  2016   29  1994  w
 5080444  A, Sohita                             IND  1447    0  1995  wi
 5706068  A. Nashir, Mohd Khairul Nazrin        MAS  1878    0        i
10201971  A.f.m., Mahfuzul Haque                BAN  1690    0        
10202650  A.k. Azad, Akand                      BAN  1692    0        i
10210997  A.K.M. Mehfuz                         BAN  2015    0        
24663832  Aab, Manfred                          GER  1808    0  1963  
 1701991  Aaberg, Anton                         SWE  2374    4  1972  
 1513966  Aabid, Ryaad                          NOR  1642    0  1958  
 1407589  Aabling-Thomsen, Jakob            f   DEN  2331   18  1985  
12524670  Aadeli, Arvin                         IRI  2015    0        
 5072662  Aadhityaa, M                          IND  1898   10  1999  
25034677  Aadish S                              IND  1528    5  1999  
 5086183  Aaditt, M K                           IND  1610    0  1996  i
 5027942  Aaditya, Jagadeesh                    IND  1814   16  1998  
25011952  Aadityan G                            IND  1621    7  2001  
 5063485  Aadityan, N.                          IND  1758    8  1996  
 1427024  Aagaard, Gert                         DEN  2030    7  1966  
 1401815  Aagaard, Jacob                    g   DEN  2506    9  1973  
 1411802  Aagaard, Kasper                       DEN  1913    0  1992  i
 1017942  Aagaard, Michael                      NED  2075    0  1960  
 1406248  Aage, Bjarke                          DEN  2068    0  1978  i
 1506064  Aagedal, Geir Ole                     NOR  1833    7  1957  
25021044  Aagney L., Narasimhan                 IND  1285    6  2000  
10205640  Aahelee, Sarker                       BAN  1577    0        w
25014510  Aakanksha Hagawane                    IND  1622    0  2000  w
25030388  Aakash Jain                           IND  1577    7  1998  
35004336  Aakash S B                            IND  1235   10  1998  
 5093295  Aakasha                               IND  1620    3  2000  w
  504599  Aakio, Seppo                          FIN  2078    0  1954  
 1402315  Aalbaek, Kurt Frede Nissen            DEN  1440    0  1944  
 1024388  Aalbers, Klaas                        NED  1891    0  1955  i
 2252465  Aalbersberg Kroon, Pedro              ESP  1878    0  1933  
 2218682  Aalders, Hendricus                    ESP  2021    0  1930  i
 1033948  Aalders, Peter                        NED  1903    0  1964  
  501956  Aaltio, Erkki                         FIN  2118    0  1935  
 1504452  Aandal, Kristian                      NOR  2012    0  1985  i
```

I program in javascript so I would ideally like to turn this into JSON, ideally so each player/id would be in their own object like so:

```
    var AllPlayers =
[{
    "2434324243":
    {
        "name":"some guy",
        "title":"f",
        "fed":"USA",
        "grade":"1999",
        "games":"3",
        "born":"1990"

    },
    "8787878887":
    {
        "name":"anyone",
        "title":"",
        "fed":"BER",
        "grade":"2222",
        "games":"6",
        "born":"1970"

    }
}
]
```

I've tried using the fs module in node to read the txt file, I then counted the length of each row(71 chars) and tried to push this to an array - however it seems that blank space gets eradicated when reading the file making this an inviable method as each persons information has a variable length.

```
  var fs = require('fs');
 var allPlayers=[];
 thisPlayer='';
 //1st row length =74
//other rows 71
 //14895 rows 
fs.readFile('jul12frl.txt', 'utf8', function(err, contents) {    
        for(let x=74;x<14895;x++){
            thisPlayer+=contents[x];
            if(thisPlayer.length==71){
                allPlayers.push(thisPlayer);
                thisPlayer='';       
            }
        }
});
```

I also tried using Excels inbuilt wizard for converting txt to an excel format- but it does not pick up all of the desired columns - it merges the Name/title/fed/grade columns into one mega column.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38201551

Comment: how in any way could he use that since he doesn't have each "property" seperated with a comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = `10207538  A E M, Doshtagir                      BAN  1864    0        i
10206612  A K M, Sourab                         BAN  1714    0        i
 5045886  A K, Kalshyan                         IND  1958    0  1964  
 8605360  A La, Teng Hua                        CHN  1915    0  1993  wi
 5031605  A, Akshaya                            IND  2016   29  1994  w
 5080444  A, Sohita                             IND  1447    0  1995  wi
 5706068  A. Nashir, Mohd Khairul Nazrin        MAS  1878    0        i
10201971  A.f.m., Mahfuzul Haque                BAN  1690    0        
10202650  A.k. Azad, Akand                      BAN  1692    0        i
10210997  A.K.M. Mehfuz                         BAN  2015    0        
24663832  Aab, Manfred                          GER  1808    0  1963  
 1701991  Aaberg, Anton                         SWE  2374    4  1972  
 1513966  Aabid, Ryaad                          NOR  1642    0  1958  
 1407589  Aabling-Thomsen, Jakob            f   DEN  2331   18  1985  
12524670  Aadeli, Arvin                         IRI  2015    0        
 5072662  Aadhityaa, M                          IND  1898   10  1999  
25034677  Aadish S                              IND  1528    5  1999  
 5086183  Aaditt, M K                           IND  1610    0  1996  i
 5027942  Aaditya, Jagadeesh                    IND  1814   16  1998  
25011952  Aadityan G                            IND  1621    7  2001  
 5063485  Aadityan, N.                          IND  1758    8  1996  
 1427024  Aagaard, Gert                         DEN  2030    7  1966  
 1401815  Aagaard, Jacob                    g   DEN  2506    9  1973  
 1411802  Aagaard, Kasper                       DEN  1913    0  1992  i
 1017942  Aagaard, Michael                      NED  2075    0  1960  
 1406248  Aage, Bjarke                          DEN  2068    0  1978  i
 1506064  Aagedal, Geir Ole                     NOR  1833    7  1957  
25021044  Aagney L., Narasimhan                 IND  1285    6  2000  
10205640  Aahelee, Sarker                       BAN  1577    0        w
25014510  Aakanksha Hagawane                    IND  1622    0  2000  w
25030388  Aakash Jain                           IND  1577    7  1998  
35004336  Aakash S B                            IND  1235   10  1998  
 5093295  Aakasha                               IND  1620    3  2000  w
  504599  Aakio, Seppo                          FIN  2078    0  1954  
 1402315  Aalbaek, Kurt Frede Nissen            DEN  1440    0  1944  
 1024388  Aalbers, Klaas                        NED  1891    0  1955  i
 2252465  Aalbersberg Kroon, Pedro              ESP  1878    0  1933  
 2218682  Aalders, Hendricus                    ESP  2021    0  1930  i
 1033948  Aalders, Peter                        NED  1903    0  1964  
  501956  Aaltio, Erkki                         FIN  2118    0  1935  
 1504452  Aandal, Kristian                      NOR  2012    0  1985  i`;


const rows = data.split("\n");
function parseRow(row) {
  const id = row.slice(0, 10).trim();
  const name = row.slice(10, 44).trim();
  const title = row.slice(44, 48).trim();
  const country = row.slice(48, 53).trim();
  const grade = row.slice(53, 60).trim();
  const games = row.slice(60, 64).trim();
  const born = row.slice(64, 70).trim();
  const flag = row.slice(70, 72).trim();
 
  return {
    id,
    name,
    title,
    country,
    grade: grade && parseInt(grade),
    games: games && parseInt(games, 10),
    born : born && parseInt(born, 10),
    flag
  }
}

const parsedRows = rows.reduce((acc, row) => {
  const parsed = parseRow(row);
  acc[parsed.id] = parsed;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(parsedRows);
```

Given that the row and columns lengths are all the same as provided in the example, you can can parse it like this:

```
// Split original string into rows as an array of strings
const rows = data.split("\n"); // could be replaced with contents read from file

function parseRow(row) {
  // Parse the values by extracting it from the row by start and end index of the column
  const id = row.slice(0, 10).trim();
  const name = row.slice(10, 44).trim();
  const title = row.slice(44, 48).trim();
  const country = row.slice(48, 53).trim();
  const grade = row.slice(53, 60).trim();
  const games = row.slice(60, 64).trim();
  const born = row.slice(64, 70).trim();
  const flag = row.slice(70, 72).trim();

  return {
    id,
    name,
    title,
    country,
    // Parse numbers
    grade: grade && parseInt(grade, 10),
    games: games && parseInt(games, 10),
    born : born && parseInt(born, 10),
    flag
  }
}

const parsed = rows.reduce((acc, row) => {
  const parsed = parseRow(row);
  acc[parsed.id] = parsed;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

It's a crude solution, but it seems to solve your problem. It did work running the example data you provided. If the full dataset differs from your example data, then you might need to update the start and end index of the various columns.

However, in the example data you provided, the columns are just white space separated. If the actual data set is tab separated, then so solution would be easier to use. `[id, name, title, country, grade, games, born, flag] = row.split('\t')`