# How to split a string by dashes and removing any outer white space?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

Goal: I want to split a string by dashes, where each array item excludes any spaces.

Example:

string -->  "CL - Destination - Airport Tax"

Ive tried :

```
var splitArray = section.split(/[-]+/);
```

Expected:

```
splitAray [0] = "CN"
splitAray [1] = "Transit "
splitAray [2] = "Airport Tax"
```

Actual:

```
splitAray [0] = "CN "
splitAray [1] = " Transit "
splitAray [2] = " Airport Tax"
```

How can I easily remove any outer spaces?

Comment: did you check `string.trim()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split the sentences by ',' and remove surrounding spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695997/split-the-sentences-by-and-remove-surrounding-spaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` with `trim`:

```js
const section = "CL - Destination - Airport Tax";
const splitArray = section.split(/[-]+/).map(s => s.trim());
console.log(splitArray);
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var section = "CL - Destination - Airport Tax";
var splitArray = section.split(/[-]+/).map(function(s) {
  return s.trim();
});
console.log(splitArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add optional whitespace on both sides of the dash:

```js
var section = "CL - Destination - Airport Tax";
var splitArray = section.split(/\s*[-]\s*/);
console.log(splitArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution map function will automatically trim each element of the array.

```
var section ="CL - Destination - Airport Tax";
var splitArray =section.split('-').map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim);
```